# Not able to connect to port different than 22 - OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I have OpenVPN network with 5 clients.

Computer with **Arch Linux** which hosts OpenVPN server,  It also hosts  virtual machine with Computer with **CentOS** which is also connnected to OpenVPN subnet. 
**Windows 8** which hosts virtual machine with **CentOS**. Both of them are connected to OpenVPN.
Last one machine is virtual machine with **CentOS** which is hosted by computer with Ubuntu 14( which is not connected to OpenVPN.

All machines in OpenVPN subnet are **bolded**. All phisical computers are in different networks.

The problem is that when I use nmap to scan Windows and it's guest virtual machine it's saids that `host seems down`.

When I force namp to scan specific port it shows `filtered` state:

```
 nmap -Pn -p 50010 n3
Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-07 19:49 CEST
Nmap scan report for n3 (10.8.0.3)
Host is up (0.11s latency).
rDNS record for 10.8.0.3: node3.com
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
50010/tcp filtered unknown
```

Telnet also cannot connect to this port

```
telnet n3 50010
Trying 10.8.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

But `ss` on this host show's proper state of this port

```
ss -anp | grep 50010
LISTEN     0      50                 10.8.0.3:50010                    *:*      users:(("java",12310,271))
```

What might be possible reason of that and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

I've found that I am able to connect via telnet to ssh port:

```
telnet n3 22
Trying 10.8.0.3...
Connected to n3.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

So it seems that it's not problem with Windows firewall. But I have no idea what it might be.

Also `nmap` result for first thousand ports:

```
nmap -Pn -p 1-1000 n3

Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-07 20:08 CEST
Nmap scan report for n3 (10.8.0.3)
Host is up (0.49s latency).
rDNS record for 10.8.0.3: node3.com
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 77.87 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your title question, it all depends on what port you're running OpenVPN on. Typically, I'll run my OpenVPN server on 443, since most firewalls allow that through. *Not* allowing that port prevents https traffic from coming through when browsing the web, so it's a pretty safe bet.

The simplest thing to do is turn the Windows Firewall *off* and try connecting again. If it connects, yeah, it was the firewall.

*However*, that *wont* solve your problem. Telnet is telling you there is no route to the host. In other words, if this is a VM setup you either have no virtual network adapter that is configured to connect to your host, or your routing table needs updating, or both.

Comment: I have added more info in first post.